# Installing nvidia driver freezes ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I wanted to install nvidia driver on ubuntu 14.04.

First Approach : I tried to use the additional drivers tab in software & updates, this approach gives me two options 1) Using nvidia binary drive 2) Using X.org X server , when trying to do the 2nd option apply changes button is blacked out while the 1st option ends up in freezing ubuntu.

Second Approach : following up this tutorial http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/ ends up also in freezing ubuntu.

After the freeze, i restart my pc and this error massage came up while booting ubuntu " unable to mount boot/efi , press s to skip mounting , press m for manual recovery " , so i use ubuntu from the advanced options for ubuntu boot option.

PS: Using duel boot win 10 & ubuntu 14.04 ( Windows 10 fast reboot disabled )

GPU: nvidia GTX 960 notebook.